# Modifying a string using character pointer

Tags: c

In C, I tried to compile following two codes:
(1)

```
char a[] = "hello";
    a[1] = 'b';
```

(2)

```
char *a  = "hello";
  a[1] = 'c';
```

First compiles successfully but second gives segmentation fault. I know, in both cases 'a' represent character pointer. Can you explain me the different behavior in the two cases. It turns out that, in second case I can access elements using a[i] but can't change it.

Comment: Please read *any* basic book about C before asking a question here.

Comment: The second case is undefined behavior since you are attempting to change the contents of a string literal.

Answer (score 4):

> **Q:** I know, in both cases 'a' represent character pointer.

**No**

Because when you declare as `char *a = "hello";`  then `a` **is pointer** of constant string literal and by doing `a[i] = 'A';` you are tring to write on read only memory that is illegal.

Whereas  in first declaration `char a[] = "hello";`, `a` **is any array** and its contents initialized by string `"hello"` that array `a[]` can be modify latterly in your code. and  doing `a[i] = 'A';`  is perfectly correct.

> **Q:** First compiles successfully but second gives segmentation fault.

Your code compiled because syntax-wise `a[i] = 'A';` is correct. But in first case (`char *a = "hello";`) instruction 
`a[1] = 'c';` modifying on constant string literal that is illegal memory operator, this instruction causes invalid action on a valid memory location that can be detected by runtime environment and send a termination signal  SIGSEGV  which results your program terminated with a segmentation-fault.

Comment: It is not correct to say that it is in `read only` memory, it probably is but it is implementation defined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go . All you can say is that it is `undefined behavior`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour yes, but its on most/standard  compilers its read only, I have give you a + after reading your answer. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Yes, most current compilers will put string literals in read-only memory, but they didn't always do that, and I believe you can still tell them not to.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson I think `-Wwrite-strings` force it to put in read only memory only by default it may be implementation dependent. Is this?

Comment: The standard says that string literals are arrays of `char` (or arrays of `wchar_t`), and it says "If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined". It does not require the compiler to put them into read-only memory. Time was, compilers generally didn't, time is, compilers generally do. (Unless you're still using Turbo C...). The `-Wwrite-strings` doesn't change a behavior, it just turns on a warning. According the the GCC documentation, the option to enable writable string constants was`-fwritable-strings`, and was deprecated in GCC 3.4, and removed in GCC 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *a = "hello";
```

Indicates a pointer to a constant string and you are trying to write on an read only memory location and hence you are getting the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

The second case is [`undefined behavior`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you are attempting to modify the contents of a string literal. Since it is undefined it can exhibit any behavior including seemingly working correctly but in this case you have a segmentation fault.